# Proper usage of PFE fullscreen addon

Tags: javascript, primefaces, codemirror, primefaces-extensions

I'm using `pe:codeMirror` component on my page to color some sql code. I would also like to include fullscreen addon on my page. I already included *fullscreen.js* on my page (using `h:outputScript`) but there is a *defineOption* function called, which is not defined since there is no *defineOption* function in *codemirror.js* file (in codemirror jar, used by project). I also tried to include the latest *codemirror.js* file from GitHub repository (which has a *defineOption* function) along with *sql.js* file to get code coloring work. The whole thing works quite ok (code coloring and fullscreen editing works, but there are some component appearance issues), but I'm not satisfied with using files from codemirror jar and some other files (from github repository) at the same time.

Is there any other option to make code coloring and fullscreen editing work without "mixing" jar files with repository files? What is a general (proper) way to include addons to a page? From jar or from separate file?

PS: Using PF 5.1, PFE 3.2.0.

Comment: Try an older version of the fullscreen.js that is compatible with the codemirror version used by PFE?

Comment: @Kukeltje It seems that PFE doesn't (fully) support addons (I guess defineOption funcion was never part of a jar file), so I'm also looking for some workaround to my problem. Just to switch my PFE codeMirror component to fullscreen somehow...